# Generating list of 2-lists in Scheme

Tags: list, scheme, cartesian-product

```
(define cart-product
  (lambda (sos1 sos2)
    (if (null? sos1) '()
      (cons
       (cart-prod-sexpr (car sos1) sos2)
       (cart-product (cdr sos1) sos2)))))

(define cart-prod-sexpr
  (lambda (s sos)
    (if (null? sos) '()
        (cons
         (list s (car sos))
         (cart-prod-sexpr s (cdr sos))))))
```

Calling `(cart-product '(q w) '(x y))` produces `(((q x) (q y)) ((w x) (w y)))`.

How I can produce `((q x) (q y) (w x) (w y))` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Untested.  Note that the `append-list` procedure I defined actually returns a list ending in `sos2`.  That is appropriate (and the right thing to do) here, but is not in general.

```
(define cart-product
  (lambda (sos1 sos2)
    (if (null? sos1) '()
      (append-list
       (cart-prod-sexpr (car sos1) sos2)
       (cart-product (cdr sos1) sos2)))))

(define cart-prod-sexpr
  (lambda (s sos)
    (if (null? sos) '()
        (cons
         (list s (car sos))
         (cart-prod-sexpr s (cdr sos))))))

(define append-list
  (lambda (sos1 sos2)
    (if (null? sos1) sos2
      (cons
        (car sos1)
        (append-list (cdr sos1) sos2)))))
```

Note that if the lists are of size n then this will take time O(n<sup>3</sup>) to produce a list of size O(n<sup>2</sup>).  <strike>Using regular `append` would take O(n<sup>4</sup>) instead.</strike> *I just implemented the regular `append` without realizing it.*  If you want to take O(n<sup>2</sup>) you have to be more clever.  As in this untested code.

```
(define cart-product
  (lambda (sos1 sos2)
    (let cart-product-finish
      (lambda (list1-current list2-current answer-current)
        (if (null? list2-current)
          (if (null? list1-current)
             answer-current
             (cart-product-finish (car list1-current) sos2 answer-current))
          (cart-product-finish list1-current (car sos2)
            (cons (cons (cdr list1-current) (cdr list2-current)) answer-current))))
    (cart-product-finish list1 '() '())))
```

In case I have a bug, the idea is to recursively loop through all combinations of elements in the first and the second, with each one replacing `answer-current` with a `cons` with one more combination, followed by everything else we have found already.  Thanks to tail-call optimization, this should be efficient.

Comment: Sorry, your solution solves the problem but it is very complicated. In other languages you use 2 nested loops. In Scheme there is _named_ _let_.

Comment: @knivil: Is there a substantially simpler solution that is as efficient?  (I'm about to simplify this one slightly, but I don't see that it can be simplified more without sacrificing efficiency.)

Answer (score 4):

Higher order functions for the win. Haskell's list comprehesion translated to Scheme for a nicer solution:

```
; cart xs ys = [ [x,y] | x <- xs, y <- ys ]
(define (cart xs ys)
  (let ((f (lambda (x) (map (lambda (y) (list x y)) ys))))
    (concatenate (map f xs))))

(cart '(a b c) '(x y)) => ((a x) (a y) (b x) (b y) (c x) (c y))
```

It runs in m*n (m = |xs|, n = |ys|). concatenate is from SRFI-1.

Comment: Shouldn't that run in m*n*n?  You generate m lists of length n, then concatenate has to traverse each list to find where to attach the head of the next list.  Still +1 for compact code.

Comment: Excellent solution. Although it took me more than an hour to figure out the mechanics. Solution first defines named let binding f which takes each element of x and generates a list of 2-lists. (map f xs) executes f for each element of xs to produce a Listof(ListOf(2-Lists)). This list is flattened into ListOf(2-List) by calling concatenate function. I hope my understanding is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head:

```
(define cart-product
  (lambda (sos1 sos2)
    (if (null? sos1) 
        '()
        (append
         (cart-prod-sexpr (car sos1) sos2)
         (cart-product (cdr sos1) sos2)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(reduce #'append 
           (mapcar #'(lambda(x)
                         (mapcar #'(lambda(y) 
                                       (list x y))
                          '(a b c))) 
           '(1 2 3)))
```

=> `((1 A) (1 B) (1 C) (2 A) (2 B) (2 C) (3 A) (3 B) (3 C))`

[Note: Solution is for Common Lisp (CLisp) and not Scheme, but I suppose it should be very similar in Scheme]

The outer (reduce #'append ) is for replacing (concatenate (map ) as given in solution by knivil

However, I am not sure how my solution stacks up on performance parameters compared to other solutions. Can somebody please comment on that?

Answer (score 1):

Here is just different solution on the same problem. I think that this is easy for understanding and maybe will be helpful for someone.

```
(define (cart-product l1 l2)
  (define (cart-product-helper l1 l2 org_l2)
    (cond
      ((and (null? l1)) `())
      ((null? l2) (cart-product-helper (cdr l1) org_l2 org_l2))
      (else (cons (cons (car l1) (car l2)) (cart-product-helper l1 (cdr l2) org_l2)))
    )
  )
  (cart-product-helper l1 l2 l2)
)
```