# (Scheme) Recursive function to compute all possible combinations of some lists?

Tags: lisp, scheme

What is an example of a recursive function to compute all possible combinations of lists?  For example, `(combine (list 1 2 3) (list 1 2))` should return `'((1 1) (1 2) (2 1) (2 2) (3 1) (3 2))`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cartesian product in Scheme](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485226/cartesian-product-in-scheme)

Comment: BTW, the inner lists aren't quoted. You should expect to get `'((1 1) (1 2) (2 1) (2 2) (3 1) (3 2))`.

Comment: My solution for 2 lists in 3 lines: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058219/generating-list-of-2-lists-in-scheme/5060091#5060091

Comment: with `(define (foreach xs fun) (map fun xs))`, it's `(define (cross xs ys) (apply append (foreach xs (lambda (x) (foreach ys (lambda (y) (list x y)))))))`... not recursive though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my solution. Requires SRFIs 1 and 26 to be available.

```
(define (cartesian-product first . rest)
  (define (iter l result)
    (define (prepend-all x)
      (map (cut cons <> x) l))
    (concatenate (map prepend-all result)))
  (map reverse (fold iter (map list first) rest)))
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's my take; I first define a helper `concat/map`, which takes a list and a function. Like regular `map`, it applies that function to each element in the list. Unlike `map`, though, it uses `append` to combine the results rather than `cons`. This is useful because we want to get back a single level of lists as an answer:

```
(define concat/map
  (lambda (ls f)
    (cond
      [(null? ls) '()]
      [else (append (f (car ls)) (concat/map (cdr ls) f))])))
```

Then, writing `combine` for two lists is straightforward. You take each element of the first list, then make every list combining it and an element `x` from the second list. Since this gives back a list of answers for each element in the first list, use `concat/map` to put it together as we want:

```
(define combine
  (lambda (xs ys)
    (concat/map xs (lambda (x)
                     (map (lambda (y) (list x y)) ys)))))
```

The version of `combine` that operates on one or more lists, let's call it `combine*`, is a bit trickier. Instead of making all the lists combining `x` with the elements from the second list, we just recursively ask for the product of all the remaining `ys`, and then `cons` `x` onto each of those results. The recursion stops when there's only two lists to combine, and uses the original `combine` in that case.

```
(define combine*
  (lambda (xs . ys*)
    (cond
      [(null? ys*) (map list xs)]
      [(null? (cdr ys*)) (combine xs (car ys*))]
      [else (concat/map xs (lambda (x)
                             (map (lambda (y) (cons x y))
                                  (apply combine* ys*))))])))
```

As a bonus, this pattern of using `concat/map` to do some work and combine the resulting answers is actually the [list monad](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Advanced_monads#The_List_monad). It's simplified here, but the structure is in place.

Comment: (a) In scheme "concat" is rarely used, "append" is much preferred; (b) your `concat/map` is also weird in that it gets the list before the function, whereas the order is almost always the other way (to accommodate more list arguments that are used for a function of more thn one input); (c) there's a subtle bug in your `combine*` -- it'll accept one argument but will break when given one; (d) finally, it would be much easier to write it using [`case-lambda`](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-lib/r6rs-lib-Z-H-6.html#node_idx_262).

Comment: @Eli Barzilay my intent with `concat/map` was to sneak the definition of the list monad's `bind` into the solution. Good catch on the single list bug.

Comment: This is another reason why Scheme et al. is a no go for me: one has to re-invent trivial stuff like list comprehension, which is available in languges that utilize more than round parentheses: [ (a,b) | a <- as, b <- bs ]

Comment: Ingo: That's true for "Scheme", but false for most actual implementations.  (That's re the re-inventing point, the parens comment is irrelevant flamebait.)

Comment: Eli: Ah! I misunderstood; I thought you meant append directly in the code for `combine*`. You're right about the name.