# Lisp: How to get all possible combinations of the elements from lists contained in a list?

Tags: list, algorithm, lisp, combinations, common-lisp

I need to write a function in Common-Lisp that takes a list of lists and returns a list containing all the possible combinations of the elements from the sublists.

So, for example calling the function on a list such as ((1 2) (1 2)) should return a list like ((1 1) (1 2) (2 1) (2 2)). The input list can be of any length and the sublists are not guaranteed to have the same length.

I know how to get this with paired elements from the sublists ( inputting ((1 2) (1 2)) returns ((1 1) (2 2)), but that's not good enough for the arc-consistency algorithm I'm trying to write, and I'm stuck.

Thank you.

Comment: what have you done so far? stackoverflow is not really a service to automagically convert informal specs into CL code. You best ask such questions showing your effort so far.

Comment: Sort-of duplicate of [(Scheme) Recursive function to compute all possible combinations of some lists?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546552/scheme-recursive-function-to-compute-all-possible-combinations-of-some-lists). Granted that's a Scheme question and not CL, but it's not hard to adapt.

Comment: What you want is basically the cartesian product of the sublists. You should be able to find solutions for your problem by looking for that term.

Comment: @Rörd Indeed, that's exactly what I searched for when trying to find a (sort-of) duplicate: I first search for `[common-lisp] cartesian` (which found nothing), then `[lisp] cartesian`, and so on.

Comment: Erm... those aren't combinations. Combinations don't allow things like `(1 2)` and `(2 1)` in the same result. That's the cartesian / cross-product. Combinations are per definition independent of the order.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was in a hurry and a little desperate, I didn't mean to ask in such a "here, fix my problem" way. This site has helped me a lot in the past, so much that I never needed to post my own question.
Anyway, those other answers linked are indeed very helpful, I always forget about Scheme. Thank you for the references and sorry for the misunderstanding

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want to use a library, here's code to do the same thing, and works with any number of lists:

```
(defun combinations (&rest lists)
  (if (endp lists)
      (list nil)
      (mapcan (lambda (inner-val)
                (mapcar (lambda (outer-val)
                          (cons outer-val
                                inner-val))
                        (car lists)))
              (apply #'combinations (cdr lists)))))

[2]> (combinations '(1 2))
((1) (2))
[3]> (combinations '(1 2) '(3 4))
((1 3) (2 3) (1 4) (2 4))
[4]> (combinations '(1 2) '(3 4) '(5 6))
((1 3 5) (2 3 5) (1 4 5) (2 4 5) (1 3 6) (2 3 6) (1 4 6) (2 4 6))
```

Comment: Tiny bug: one would expect `(combinations '(1 2) '(3 4) '())` and `(combinations '(1 2) '() '(3 4))` to be `nil`, like `(combinations '() '(1 2) '(3 4))`. However, the three results are different. Thus the function works if no list beyond the first is empty.

Comment: @ user1220978: You're right. The problem was that I was using `(if (car lists)` to check for the end of the lists, but that would also be false for an empty list argument. I'm editing my answer to use `endp` to check for the end instead, with this change the function will also correctly return the empty list if it gets any empty lists in its arguments.

Comment: @zck: Sorry, I was confused which of the answers here was mine and which was yours. Anyone, please disregard the parts in my previous comment where I call this "my answer".

Comment: Haha, no worries. It was like five years ago, and did fix a bug. :-p

Answer (score 6):

wvxvw removed their answer that pointed to a function from Alexandria, but it does provide a very similarly named function that actually does what you want. Instead of `alexandria:map-combinations`, you need `alexandria:map-product`, e.g.

```
(apply #'alexandria:map-product #'list '((1 2) (1 2)))
```

evaluates to

```
((1 1) (1 2) (2 1) (2 2))
```

Comment: I realized I got confused about what OP really wanted. Whether there was a mistake in the example, or the naming, so I decided to remove the answer, just so not to keep the confusion going.