# Why collect function does not work in this Lisp code

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am unable to figure out why following function is not working. I am trying to make it return a list of lists showing all combinations: `((1 5) (1 6) (1 7) (2 5) (2 6) (2 7) (3 5) (3 6) (3 7))`

```
(defun combo3 (list1 list2)
    (dolist (e1 list1)
        (dolist (e2 list2)
            collect '(e1 e2))))


> (combo3 '(1 2 3) '( 5 6 7) )
NIL
```

Edit: In response to the answer, I tried to use loop macro with collect. Collect is not working in following loop :

```
(defun combo4 (list1 list2)
   (loop for element1 in list1 do 
        (loop for element2 in list2 do
               collect (list element1 element2))))

> (combo4 '(1 2 3) '( 5 6 7) )
NIL
```

I have tried to make it work without nconc. Does collect always need nconc?

Comment: `COLLECT` is not a function. It's part of the `LOOP`-macro, and as such can only be used inside a `LOOP`.

Comment: Re edit: The `COLLECT` in the inner loop creates the sublists, so you need the outer loop to have a clause to join those into a single list. Also, you shouldn't have those `DO`s there. `DO` is not part of the `FOR ... IN ...` construct, rather it's a separate statement used for executing forms (like `COLLECT` and `NCONC`, except that `DO` discards the result).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lisp: How to get all possible combinations of the elements from lists contained on a list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675913/lisp-how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-of-the-elements-from-lists-contained)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of problems...

First, `collect` is part of the `loop` macro (or facility, if you prefer), so is going to cause problems when used within `dolist`.

Second, even if `collect '(e1 e2)` *did* collect something, it (probably) wouldn't be what you want, since it would end up with a list like `((e1 e2) (e1 e2) (e1 e2) (e1 e2) (e1 e2) (e1 e2))`.

What you (probably) want is something like:

```
(defun cross-product (list1 list2)
   (loop for element1 in list1
      nconc (loop for element2 in list2
               collect (list element1 element2))))
```

Comment: It does not work without nconc. Please see edit in my question.

Comment: @rnso The inner loop uses `collect` to build three lists, `((1 4) (1 5) (1 6))` and similarly for 2 and 3. These are returned to the outer loop, where we want to combine them. This can be done either using `nconc` or `append`, but in this case we *know* we have fresh lists, so we might as well use `nconc` to concatenate them destructively. You need some sort of accumulation in the outer loop, otherwise it just returns `nil`. And as a general rule, please don't edit your question to ask a new question, simply ask a new question.