# All combinations of list elements without duplicate elements

Tags: mapping, common-lisp, combinations

[Alexandria](https://common-lisp.net/project/alexandria/draft/alexandria.html#Conses) has a function `map-product` which takes an arbitrary number of list arguments, and generates all combinations of elements, one from each list, in order. For example:

```
(alexandria:map-product 'list '(1 2) '(3 4) '(5 6))
=> ((1 3 5) (1 3 6) (1 4 5) (1 4 6) (2 3 5) (2 3 6) (2 4 5) (2 4 6))
```

And when there are duplicate elements in the arguments, the resulting combinations will also contain some duplicate elements:

```
(alexandria:map-product 'list '(1 2) '(3 4) '(5 1))
=> ((1 3 5) (1 3 1) (1 4 5) (1 4 1) (2 3 5) (2 3 1) (2 4 5) (2 4 1))
```

where (1 3 1) and (1 4 1) contain duplicates.

I would like to remove all such lists containing duplicates from the result. My current solution is to simply do:

```
(delete-if-not #'alexandria:setp result)
```

but this requires an exorbitant amount of post-processing, especially since the number of resulting combinations is typically in the hundreds. A better solution would be to write a function like `map-product` that did not generate duplicates in the first place.

Another post at [Lisp: How to get all possible combinations of the elements from lists contained on a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675913/lisp-how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-of-the-elements-from-lists-contained) by zck provides a function roughly equivalent to `map-product` that seems like it could be modified to excise duplicates internally:

```
(defun combinations (&rest lists)
  (if (car lists)
      (mapcan (lambda (inner-val)
                (mapcar (lambda (outer-val)
                          (cons outer-val
                                inner-val))
                        (car lists)))
              (apply #'combinations (cdr lists)))
    (list nil)))
```

However, it is not obvious to me how to insert a duplicates test. Also, a simple timing run seems to show that this function is about 16 times slower than `alexandria:map-product`. Is it feasible to get a faster version of this function, but without duplicate combinations?

Comment: `map-product` typically can't take an arbitrary number of arguments. See the variable `CALL-ARGUMENTS-LIMIT`. Your `COMBINATIONS` function has the same limitation.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. Looks like it will not be a problem, at least in SBCL!  CALL-ARGUMENTS-LIMIT = 4611686018427387903.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to check this for correctness, but it should give you an idea:

```
CL-USER 40 > (defun combinations-1 (lists)
               (if (car lists)
                   (mapcan (lambda (inner-val)
                             (mapcan (lambda (outer-val)
                                       (unless (member outer-val inner-val)
                                         (list (cons outer-val inner-val))))
                                     (car lists)))
                           (combinations-1 (cdr lists)))
                 (list nil)))
COMBINATIONS-1

CL-USER 41 > (combinations-1 '((3 2) (1 2) (5 1)))
((3 1 5) (2 1 5) (3 2 5) (3 2 1))
```

Another MAPCAN instead of MAPCAR filters the NILs. For that we need to return lists, thus the added LIST call. We add something to the list only, if it is not a member, otherwise the empty list is used.

Note that I also removed the &rest list / apply pattern.

Q: Are all sublists with repetitions reduced to NIL, so that they are removed via the MAPCAN?